# What can we say about functions like $f: \mathcal{F}(X;Y) \to \mathcal{F}(X;W)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X,Y,W$ be non-empty sets. How can we relate $\mathcal{F}(X;Y)$ and $\mathcal{F}(X;W)$ using relations between Y and W? For example, are there any injection or surjection between $\mathcal{F}(X;Y)$ and $\mathcal{F}(X;W)$ if $Y \subset W$? And if exists an injection or surjection between $Y$ and $W$?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}(X;Y)$ is the space of functions from $X$ into $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us use a slightly more standard notation: $\mathcal{F}(A;B) = (A{\to}B)$. Moreover, let us sloppily interpret a map simply as a set of pairs (rather than as a triple). Finally, let us use the symbol $\circ$ for right composition.

If $Y \subset W$, then $(X{\to}Y) \subset (X{\to}W)$.

If there is an injection $\alpha\colon Y\hookrightarrow W$, then $(X{\to}Y)\to (X{\to}W)$, $f\mapsto \alpha{\circ}f$ is an injection, and there need not be any surjection from $X{\to}Y$ to $X{\to}W$ (find a counterexample!).

Assuming the axiom of choice, if there is a surjection $\beta\colon Y\twoheadrightarrow W$, then the map $(X{\to}Y)\to(X{\to}W)$, $f\mapsto\beta{\circ}f$ is a surjection (prove it!), and there need not be any injection from $X{\to}Y$ to $X{\to}W$ (find a counterexample!).